# Prove that convex function is bounded from below

Tags: convex-analysis, maxima-minima

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Prove that $f$ is bounded from below, that $f$ has a maximum and that this maximum is $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.

I need some help. I think some information is missing, but probably not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in [a,b]$ then we can write $x=ta+(1-t)b$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Hence $f(x)\leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b) \leq t\max \{f(a),f(b)\}+ (1-t) \max \{f(a),f(b)\}=\max \{f(a),f(b)\}$

Proof of the fact that $f$ is bounded below: On any closed sub interval of $(a,b)$ the function is continuous, Hence bounded. Hence, if $f$ is not bounded below then there exist a sequence $x_n$ converging to $a$ or $b$ such that $f(x_n) \to -\infty$. Suppose $x_n \to a$. Write $\frac {a+b} 2 $ as $\lambda_n x_n +(1-\lambda_n) b$. Compute $\lambda_n$ from this equation and observe that $\lambda_n \to \frac 1 2$. Now take limits in $f(\frac {a+b} 2 ) \leq \lambda_n f(x_n) +(1-\lambda_n) f(b)$ to get the contradiction $f(\frac {a+b} 2 )=-\infty$.

Comment: could you explain me why $tmax\{f(a),f(b)\}+(1−t)max\{f(a),f(b)\} $ is equal to $max\{f(a),f(b)\}$.

Comment: @ElricEd $tC+(1-t)C=(t+(1-t))C=(1)(C)=C$ where $C=\max \{f(a),f(b)\}$.

Comment: ah, ok ! makes sense... any idea about the lower bound?

Comment: @ElricEd Lower bound need not be attained at $a$ or $b$. Take $f(x)=x^{2}$ for example.

Comment: i can see. but for this case, what informations i have besides $f$ is convex to find lower bound?

Comment: Convexity is not useful for the minimum.

Comment: well ... what's left to solve then?

Comment: no, it isn't lol

Comment: @ElricEd Sorry, I misread the question. I have  now given a proof of the fact that $f$ is bounded below.